# No credentials specified Fetching changes from the remote Git

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to do my first Jenkins job. I want to run a java project that uploaded to git but I get this error while building the job:

---

> No credentials specified Fetching changes from the remote Git
> repository ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from
> https://gitlab/engineering/automation/create_pass_criteria.git    at
> hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:908)  at
> hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1123)   at
> hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1159)  at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
> Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress
> https://gitlab/engineering/automation/create_pass_criteria.git
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: fatal: unable to access
> 'https://gitlab/engineering/automation/create_pass_criteria.git/':
> Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.

---

This is my groovy jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
    agent { node { label "agent_314" } }

    stages {

        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                echo "Building..."
                git 'https://gitlab/engineering/automation/create_pass_criteria.git'
                sh './mvnw clean compile'
            }
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to access to a private repository, you need to first configure the credentials (either for job or global) and then specify in the git checkout
`git credentialsId: 'GITLAB_CREDENTIALS', url: 'https://gitlab/engineering/automation/create_pass_criteria.git`
[Check the docs for more info](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#using-credentials)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add credentials in Jenkins for your git repository and then supply the credentials in pipeline for git checkout

To Add credentials -
Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins ->Manage Credentials
Under Stores scoped to Jenkins , click on Jenkins  then click on Global Credentials (unrestricted) .

From left side click on Add Credentials and Define the username and password for your git repository and note down credentialsID

Add below line in your jenkinsfile

git credentialsId: 'your git credentials ID', url: 'https://gitlab/engineering/automation/create_pass_criteria.git'

For more information you can refer [here](https://gist.github.com/blaisep/eb8aa720b06eff4f095e4b64326961b5)